# Track access violation in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, access-violation

I'd like to track an access violation error which is triggered.

Threads are created and perform some jobs. I suspect them to access VCL or variables without "synchronise". 
The Madexcept report show that the access violation occurs on the form close (form1.close;), but no more precision.

I've got many lines of codes (around 100.000).

What should I do  to avoid spending too much time ? 
I've checked "range checking" in the debugger option.

Many thanks

Comment: Form close access violation, is usually freeing a freed object, or possibly threads trying to synchronise back to the vcl thread while the form and it's stuff is in the process of being freed. First thing you should do in OnClose is close off all the threads, or set some property in them they can use to not synchronise. After that it's putting debugs on all the destructors of stuff you've written that closing the form will call. Oh and any Finalizations if you have them.

Comment: Not IME. Freeing an object that was freed only shortly before very seldom results in an AV. Still running threads are a possibility.

Comment: Then, the error occurs on a customer PC so that I can not debug, evne not remote debug.

Comment: An AV at such a low memory access is usually an indication that a member of an object was accessed via a nil pointer.

Comment: madExcept disassembly report will tell you exactly what is nil

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to know, you can build the project with debug dcu's and put a breakpoint just before the point the exception occurs.

Now you can jump into the VCL code and hopefully see what goes wrong.

But access violations in close or destructors are often because of double freeïng of object.  For example, you free component that is also freed by the form (because it is owned by the form).

Comment: Freeing a component that is owned by the form is harmless, because the component will tell its owner to remove itself from its Components list, so after the component was freed, the owner does not know about the component anymore, so it will not try to free it a second time. Access violations far more often happen because of uninitialised pointers or references that point to some random address, or accesses to nil.

Comment: An AV at such a low memory access is usually an indication that a member of an object was accessed via a nil pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SafeMM](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/28681), it will help you to catch errors sooner. Here is the [video](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/27285) which gives detailed explanations.
But be careful, this MM is only for debugging, don't enable it in Release versions of your software.